# Unable to run node application using pm2

Tags: node.js, nestjs, pm2, node-mssql

I made a small nestjs webapp, it connects to a local mssql database and works fine... Except if I try to launch it using pm2.

- regular `yarn start:dev` works (it translates to `nest start --watch`)
- building the production and running `yarn start:prod` also works fine (it translates to `node dist/main`)
- running `nodemon build/main.js` also works fine

But if I try to launch my app running `pm2 start build/main.js` I get DB connection errors: `TypeError: The "config.server" property is required and must be of type string`.

My DB connection parameters are currently stored in a .env file. I load them running `env.config()` and it's working fine  for the other three running methods I listed. I've tried to change the parameters to include quotes and double quotes, with no luck:

- `db_host = localhost`
- `db_host = 'localhost'`
- `db_host = "localhost"`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From where the `env.config()` method is comming exactly? did you have more than one `.env`? 
(btw I'm using locally with PM2)

Comment: @MicaelLevi in my application's root there's only one .env file, all parameters come from this file

Comment: I just learned that this application won't work using this syntax, despite nodemon running normally. I had to use a syntax like `pm2 start npm --name "myApp" -- run start:prod` to start it correctly.

Comment: oh right. In my app I was building it (via `nest build` in [`pre` hook](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scripts#pre--post-scripts)) before running `pm2 start` (which will run `node dist/src/main.js`) and not relying on `start:prod` npm-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just found out that changing the syntax from `pm2 start` to something like `pm2 start npm --name "myApp" -- run start:prod` worked.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you, in the documentation says you can use the environment variables in ecosystem.config.js file:
https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/environment/